Unable to populate users and matches information from MongoDB
I am currently building out a dating app in React and I am having some problem populating users information based on their gender preferences. It seems like I am able to fetch the user's profile with no issue but unable to fetch users with compatible interests.
The last console.log at the bottom for compatibleUsers currently prints out an empty array '[]', but the top console.log for users is working.
Copilot is telling me to check the case sensitivity of my MongoDB document but I have it correct:
{
  "\_id":{"$oid":"660c165c29a4f35ac5ebf60d"},
  "user_id":"8c76db38-ba8d-46e1-a2c7-1f43e46d0d20",
  "email":"testing6@email.com",
  "hashed_password":"$2b$10$KhJOgnaYjsgWJC2vTHxTq.fGgVKtm.qxPuBYCphG7I1dPJOrziH/q",
  "about":"Explore another city",
  "date_of_birth":"1986-04-17T15:29:49.000Z",
  "full_name":"Bouchard",
  "gender_identity":"man",
  "gender_interest":"women",
  "matches":\[\]
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Dashboard.js
// Fetch user profile.
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user', {
      params: {userId}
    })
    setUser(response.data);
    return;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('A1', err)
  }
}
  
  // Get compatible users of same interest.
  const getCompatibleUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/compatible-users', {
        params: { gender_identity: user?.gender_interest } 
      })
      console.log('Compatible Users Response:', response.data);
      setCompatibleUsers(response.data)
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log('A2', err)
    } 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, [userId]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && !compatibleUsers) {
      getCompatibleUsers();
    }
  }, [user]);
  
  console.log('User:', user)
  console.log('Compatible Users:', compatibleUsers)

Server: index.js
// Fetch individual user.
app.get("/user", async (req, res) => {
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  const userId = req.query.userId 

  console.log('userId:', userId) // Delete when done testing.

  try {
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db("app-data");
    const users = database.collection("users");

    const query = { user_id: userId }
    const user = await users.findOne(query)
    res.send(user)
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('B3', error);
  } finally {
    await client.close()
  }
});

// Fetch compatible users.
app.get("/compatible-users", async (req, res) => {
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  const genderIdentity = req.query.gender_identity;

  console.log('Interest: ', genderIdentity) // Delete when done testing.

  try {
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db("app-data");
    const users = database.collection("users");
    const query = { gender_identity: { $eq: genderIdentity } }; 
    const foundUsers = await users.find(query).toArray();

    console.log('Found Users:', foundUsers);

    res.send(foundUsers);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('B4', err);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
});

I've tried inputting multiple console.log throughout the functions to get the response and currently only the log for 'users' in Dashboard.js and 'Interest:' in index.js works.
The console.log for 'compatibleUsers' and 'Found Users:' shows up as empty arrays.

Do you get anything with this line in your server: console.log('Interest: ', genderIdentity)? Also, do you get anything if you hardcode a specific value for gender_identity? Are there any users with that particular gender_identity in your database?

Have you checked that /compatible-users endpoint directly? for example from postman? do you get results? (That will also tell you if the problem is on the server side or client side)

For the user schema above, the log for Interest:  does show up as 'Interest:  women' but the console.log('Found Users:', foundUsers); shows up as 'Found Users: []' @FiddlingAway

If I go to http://localhost:8000/compatible-users from Postman I get an empty array @Pipe
